# javascript - Array.map with String.trim

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the following work? (Chrome, so no issues with Arrays.map missing)

```
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(String.prototype.trim)

TypeError: String.prototype.trim called on null or undefined
```

Comment: The problem is, that `map()` will pass the element as a parameter to the callback and `trim()` has to be called as a method of some string-object (no parameter).

Comment: `String.prototype.trim.call(" x ")` works, but why not `[" x "].map(String.prototype.trim.cal)l` doesn't?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452607/4510033).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`map` passes each element of the array as parameter to the function:

```
[element1, e2].map(myFunction); // --> myFunction(element1); myFunction(e2)
```

`String.prototype.trim` is not a function that you pass a string to be trimmed. You call the function as a method of that string, instead:

```
" some string ".trim(); // "some string"
```

To use `trim` in a `.map`, you'll need to do something like:

```
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(e => e.trim());
```

Comment: Or in ES6 it would be written like so: `[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(e => e.trim())`

Comment: All the `.trim()` fx on these answers are giving me "element.trim is not a function". What could cause that? --Solved. It because each of my elements is an array.

Answer (score 9):

One shorter version with an arrow function:

```
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(e => e.trim());
```

Answer (score 5):

That's actually because `Array.map()` function should have a `currentElement` as an argument, while `String.prototype.trim` doesn't take any arguments, therefore we can't call it that way.
So, you'll have to do it hard way:

```
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(function(elem){
     return elem.trim();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## Learn how `this` works.

---

### Do either

```js
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "]
.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
```

or

```js
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(fetch.call.bind("".trim))
// .map(<a whatever function>.call.bind(<a whatever string>.trim))
```

or simply

```js
[" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(s => s.trim())
```

.

---

### Why not—

#### `….map(String.prototype.trim)`?

Because the `trim` function trims `this`, not its argument. It does not have any parameters. You do `" no ".trim()` (`" no "` being the `this`), not `trim(" no ")`.

#### `….map(String.prototype.trim.call)` when the `call` forwards the first argument as `this`?

Because, in this example, the function which the `call` function forwards to, is not `String.prototype.trim`, but `undefined`. The `call` function forwards to *its* `this`, and in this example, the `call` function is called without `this`, as if you do `(undefined).call(…)`.

This example is the same as doing:

```js
const _call = String.prototype.trim.call;
// _call has no `this`.
….map(_call)
```

and in this case, the `_call` function’s `this` is not `String.prototype.trim`, unlike the direct call `String.prototype.trim.call(…)` (in the form of `<this>.<function>()`). The `_call` variable is a mere `function` value that does not retain `String.prototype.trim` as its `this`.

For the `call` function to retain `String.prototype.trim` as its default `this`, you need to use the `Function.prototype.bind` function to bind the specific `this`, `String.prototype.trim`, to it. The `bind` function also forwards arguments.

```js
const call_without_this = Function.prototype.call;
const trim_without_this = String.prototype.trim;
const call_with_trim_as_its_this =
    call_without_this.bind(trim_without_this);
….map(call_with_trim_as_its_this)
```

The function returned by the `bind` function call, `call_with_trim_as_its_this`, is a function that calls the `call` function with `this` of `trim_without_this` and arguments being forwarded, that is, a function that calls `trim_without_this` with `this` of the first argument.

And also, since properties in the prototype of a class are inherited by instances of the class, `<class>.prototype.<property>` can be replaced with `<the class’ instance>.<property>`.

```js
const call_without_this = fetch.call;
const trim_without_this = "".trim;
const call_with_trim_as_its_this =
    call_without_this.bind(trim_without_this);
….map(call_with_trim_as_its_this)
```

Answer (score -2):

With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html) (functional programming library for Javascript):

```
> var R = require('ramda')
undefined
> [" a ", "b", " c", "d "].map(R.trim)
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

This example was made using the [built-in node repl](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).